# How to sovle issue of foreign key constraints fail?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

```
ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails 
(`shahzain`.`branch`, CONSTRAINT `branch_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mgr_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`emp_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)
```

This is issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear.

You are trying to insert a row in `branch` whose `mgr_id` does not exists in column `emp_id` of table `emp`. You have a foreign key constraint that prohibits that.

Either add the missing employee in `emp`, or attach the `branch` to another manager, that exists in employee.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means there is some flaw in the design of your code. 
Look at the sequence of insert/updates you are doing.

1.Upsert(Insert or Update) the table employee with newid, name etc of employee

2.Add a row in Branch table, with the information of bank to which this employee is a manager of.

```
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, dept, age, salary) VALUES (105, 'Srinath', 'Aeronautics', 27, 33000)

INSERT INTO branch (id,  mgr_id, name, branchaddress) VALUES (5, 105, 'Michigan Branch', '1000 MainStreet')
```